# Force GCC to return floats in integer registers

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64, calling-convention

When targeting the x86(-32) architecture, GCC provides a way to completely disable generation of x87 FPU instructions and instead generate calls to library functions which do floating-point math in software. This was historically provided because some early x86 CPUs (i386, i486SX) didn't always have a hardware FPU available. This also proves to be useful in code where the FPU is not available (e.g. kernel code), though usually kernel code doesn't actually use floating-point math at all.

This functionality is easily accessed by using `-mgeneral-regs-only`, which will disable usage of x87, SSE, AVX and so on. This does require a version of `libgcc` which contains [these](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Soft-float-library-routines.html) routines. It could also technically be done only for x87 by using `-msoft-float -mno-fp-ret-in-387` (this would allow to compiler to still make optimizations using SSE, but that's not very useful in this context)

What I want to do is find a way to use this functionality on x86-64. Since x86-64 provides a minimum of SSE2, GCC defaults to that for FP math and `-msoft-float` does nothing (unless you also set `-mfpmath=387`, in which case it does generate library calls). The x86-64 ABI also mandates that FP values are passed in XMM registers. This seems to be easily bypassed by using `-mgeneral-regs-only`, making the compiler pass all FP arguments on the stack and also generate library calls for FP routines.

The problem I face is that the ABI demands that FP values are returned in the XMM register, and there doesn't seem to be any switch to disable that (unlike in x86-32, where it is possible to disable returning in ST0, even though it is also in violation of the ABI). Is there any way to make the compiler return FP values in integer registers?

As you can see in this [Godbolt Example](https://godbolt.org/z/n98cfWznM), the compiler specifically dislikes **returning** FP. It doesn't mind passing parameters, which is why the function that takes a `double` and returns `int` (as well as the library call to `__fixdfsi`) works, while the function that returns a `double` only works in x86-32.

EDIT: It seems that the problem is deeper than I thought. The compiler also [refuses to violate the System V ABI for `long double`](https://godbolt.org/z/7e1Gh37TK), even though it should return in ST0 rather than XMM0. The same exact flags work in 32-bit mode (returns in `ecx:edx:eax`), but fail in 64-bit mode (specifically, `-mno-fp-ret-in-387` does nothing).

Comment: What is the *underlying* problem you think putting floating-point values in general register will solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude avoid using the FPU (while still allowing floating point C code) in contexts where the FPU can't be used.

Comment: @DarkAtom which contexts the FPU can't be used? Kernel code can use the FPU without problem as long as you call the functions to save the context properly

Comment: That's most likely what I will end up doing. This question was more of a "is it possible without cluttering C code with begin-end blocks and instead use soft float?" so I thought why not just ask?

Comment: If this was C++ you could write a trivial wrapper class with one member of type `uint64_t` (so that it gets passed and returned in general registers), and cast operators to and from `double` that perform a bitcast.

Comment: @NateEldredge but that won't help for `long double`

Comment: You can trick the compiler a bit by [making the return type a union](https://godbolt.org/z/Weh87fcMK). But that doesn't help with long double, which will be returned on the stack instead. However, I don't think that's necessarily a bad thing. The only way to load a long double from GP registers is via memory, right?  Why force two loads and stores (or 3 in 32 bit mode) at every call just to get the long double in and out of GP registers?

Comment: I don't want any modification to valid C code. If that were the case, I would use a begin-end block which is much easier and forget about it.

Comment: @phuclv I don't necessarily wish for `long double` to be returned in registers (like GCC does it in `ecx:edx:eax`). Returning on the stack like a struct is fine too, if that's possible to achieve.

Comment: @Homer512 the example you provided doesn't work, because it uses SSE and x87 registers. If you add `-mgeneral-regs-only`, the compiler says that it wants to return in SSE or x87 (even though if you don't use the option it returns in RAX and the stack, respectively). But, as I said, I don't want any trickery in C code. It should be done only using compiler options if possible.

Comment: @phuclv: For `long double` you can use an `unsigned __int128` and get it returned in `rdx:rax`.

Comment: @DarkAtom: It is sounding like that is just not possible.